# QML c++ signal & slots

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I've got following code:

**main.cpp**

```
QDeclarativeView *qmlView = new QDeclarativeView();
qmlView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/nav.qml"));
ui->nav->addWidget(qmlView);
Blockschaltbild bild;
QObject *value = qmlView->rootObject();
QObject::connect(value, SIGNAL(testSig()), &bild, SLOT(BlockSlot()));
```

The signals and slots connect correctly. (QObject::connect returns "true")

**qml file:**

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    ....
    signal testSig()
    MouseArea{
         id: mousearea
         anchors.fill: parent
         onEntered: parent.color = onHoverColor
         onExited:  parent.color = parent.buttonColor
         onClicked: {
                        rectangle1.testSig()
                        console.log("Button clicked")
                    }
    }
}
```

This is where the slot is located:

**Blockschaltbild.h**

```
class Blockschaltbild: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void BlockSlot(){
        cout << "Slot is working" << endl;
    }
public:
    ....
}
```

If I click on the mouse area, the console shows "Button clicked" but not "Slot is working".
I use Qt 4.8.4 with QtQuick 1.1. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is it a typo that you wrote `restSig()` instead of `testSig()`? And does the rectangle have an `id: rectangle1`?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I just corrected it. rectangle1 is the id of rectangle. I just forgot to write it in there.

Comment: Try to move BlockSlot definition to the .cpp file, because Qt will generate MOC file and link it with cpp file.

Comment: Have yout tried that `cout << "sth"` in some other place and it worked?
For me I have to use `qDebug() << "sth"` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you simply require to work with your Blockschaltbild object in QML, you can also decide against a loose coupling with signal and slots and simply pass your object as a context parameter, to make it available in QML.

```
QDeclarativeView *qmlView = new QDeclarativeView();
qmlView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/nav.qml"));
ui->nav->addWidget(qmlView);

Blockschaltbild* bild;
QObject *value = qmlView->engine().rootContext()->setContextProperty("bild", bild);
```

You can then call the BlockSlot() slot of your object from QML with:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    ....

    MouseArea{
       id: mousearea
       anchors.fill: parent
       onEntered: parent.color = onHoverColor
       onExited:  parent.color = parent.buttonColor
       onClicked: {
           bild.BlockSlot() // call BlockSlot of "bild" context property
           console.log("Button clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

It is also possible to use *qmlRegisterType*, which allows you to create instances of your Blockschaltbild class with QML. See [here](https://v-play.net/cross-platform-development/how-to-expose-a-qt-cpp-class-with-signals-and-slots-to-qml#register-and-use-your-cpp-qml-type) for more information.